# Dynamically disabling menu based on database query?

Tags: database, dynamic

So I'm not a programmer, but my friend is. He's trying to help me develop a web/phone app but we are stuck because I'm having trouble communicating to him an idea and he is having trouble understanding. One or both of us is a moron ;)  Part of the problem is that I don't even know where to search for the answer cuz I don't know the specific search terms...believe me I've tried...and I've searched stack overflow as well.  Here is the problem:

Short Question:
Websites (like hotel search) allow you to search for rooms by selecting checkboxes in certain categories (i.e. smoking/nonsmoking, stars, size of bed, near downtown, etc.). Certainly these sites are referencing a large database of hotels in a city.

How can you create a site so that as you check boxes (narrow your search), other options which are no longer available are dynamically "grayed out" or disabled on the fly so you cannot check those boxes.  So if I were to check 4 stars and that excluded all smoking rooms based on the database, then the option to check "smoking" would be disabled.

The key to this is that the site is querying a database as you click boxes, then based on the results of that query (which is presumably many rows of data (a subset)), it is analysing that subset of data to determine whether checkbox options should be on/off, then dynamically "graying out" specific options that are no longer available.  Once you got to only a single possible result, then the site would pop up the website for that hotel (or some other action).

What is this called?  Where can I get more information on this.  Any pointing toward the right direction would be tremendously appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance!

Roy

HERE IS AN EDIT TO ORIGINAL QUESTION...HERE IS AN EXAMPLE:

[image: Database]

So here is my sample database.  Each Column (i.e. AA, AB, AC) represents a checkbox.  '1'= True, '0'= False, and '2'= Either.  Therefore, if you click checkbox AA, then only the top three rows would meet the criteria of AA=True.  So query would return the top three rows.  The '2's could be either True/False so since they don't affect outcome, those checkboxes should be disabled and only the checkboxes CA,CB, & CC should remain choosable.  If you then click checkbox CB, then result ZYX would be output.

Conceptually, How do you go from the initial click to the point where the database is queried and the results are used to dynamically change the menu.  People have suggested javascript but i am not looking for a language.  I am more looking for the concept.  I was thinking that the query would return a new "temp" array with just the top three rows.  Then each column of this "temp" array would be queried to see if it contained a '1' in any of the rows.  If it did, then that button would be turned "ON".  If it didn't then that button would be turned "OFF".  Is this confusing?  Am I asking for too much ;)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like javascript could help. For example, using jQuery, you can dynamically send queries to databases based on whatever you click on checkboxes, and then reload a particular section of the webpage. Javascript can also dynamically disable checkboxes.

Comment: hey wei, i think everything that i come upon talking about dynamic updating of menu choices points to javascript...i guess I'm not getting how you go from a simple query of your database based on a 'button press' to a refresh of the menu...conceptually.  i will post more info on my original question.